# Entity Framework Code First Migration during deploy to production host does not work

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I am using VS2013 with Entity Framework 6.1 against SQL 2012.

When I use Code First to create my classes and tables in Dev it works fine.
When I go to publish via Web Deploy to my third party host everything deploys but none of the tables are created in the DB. The connection string/s contain the appropriate username and password for a user that has table create access to the DB. (Tested because I use the same login/password via SSMS 
to create tables on the hosted SQL server successfully)
The Database publish connection string is being made correctly and has the correct values.

When I deploy the ASP.Net MVC app with the Execute Code First Migrations checkbox marked the app throws a 500 error on the hosted server.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you get the error from the server?  EFCF migrations run on context initialization, so they might not be getting run if there's an error; or, they might be the cause.  Manually changing the schema is not a good fix for this, as it will then block the migration from being able to run later ("table Foo already exists" type errors).

Comment: I'm not able to get the exact error yet. If I remove the "Execute Code First Migrations" the error does go away so I assume it has to do with the initialization.

Comment: Set up a global error handler (Controller) that shows error description in a View. The View would be typed to `@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo`. And display `@Model.Exception.Message`. This way you'll see the exact error message issued by EF.

Comment: I understand the View part of your statement but I am a little unclear about setting up a Controller as a global error handler. Any examples or further clarification you can give me?  I currently have Elmah installed and configured on the project but am not able to get any response back from that. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer in a couple of minutes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I have to determine there was an EntityFramework section added to the deployed Web.config that was not located in my local version of Web.config. The error was being caused by there being a EntityFramework section but there was no section descriptor specifying that there was an EntityFramework section.

I added the section descriptor and everything works correctly.

I'm not sure why the transform was happening when things were being deployed but the transform was incomplete.

Comment: Ah, tricky.  That section is added to set the DbInitializer for enabling Migrations to run.  This is how VS ensures that the initializer is correct for migrations as opposed to, say, using DropAndCreateAlways which you might have enabled for local development.

Comment: Funny though, registering that section should happen as part of installing the EF nugget package.  Did you install via Nuget?

Comment: Yes via Nuget. I'm going to try a couple of hello world projects from scratch to see if the issue is persistent.

Comment: Tried several hello world projects and the appropriate section is added automatically so the issues seems to be an anomaly.

Comment: I don't understand "add section descriptor", but code, step by step instructions, or a link to adding a "section descriptor" would earn you an upvote from me. I was able to fix my issue by reinstalling EF (which was a painful process), and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a misunderstanding of how the VS Web Deployment feature handles EFCF Migrations.

Normally (non-EFCF), VS publishes your files to the remote server and updates your database schema.  By the time the deployment is complete, all changes have been applied.

With EFCF migrations, this is not the case.  VS's deployment will modify your web.config to set up the connection strings needed for the database.  This is reflected in the published files, but the DB has not been touched at all yet.  The changes to the DB don't take place until the migrations code runs.  This happens by default the first time your code initializes your DbContext; the DbInitializer will execute any migrations that have not been applied.  Generally, this means you have to request a page from your site to trigger this process.

To expound a little bit on my comment:

> Manually changing the schema is not a good fix for this, as it will then block the migration from being able to run later ("table Foo already exists" type errors).

If you've made changes to the DB that are incompatible with the Migrations code, you'll get an exception from EF.  For example, you might have this migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Foo",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Value = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

}
```

If you've manually created table Foo (e.g. because you didn't see it after deployment), EF can no longer apply this migration, and throws an exception.  This can be the cause of the HTTP 500 errors you were seeing.

Comment: I am positive that the error is coming on DbInitializer. I am not making any manual changes to the tables or database. In fact the db is totally devoid of any of my tables.

Comment: @Jimmy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739543/migrations-are-not-taking-place-after-pushing-my-code-on-heroku can you ans quite similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would set up error pages in your application.

In your `Web.config` under `<system.web>` you would have

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/Error400" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Error403" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />
</customErrors>
```

So, the `defaultRedirect` would catch the 500 error.

Your `Error` controller could look as follows.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    public ActionResult Error400()
    {
        return View("Error400");
    }

    public ActionResult Error403()
    {
        return View("Error403");
    }

    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View("Error404");
    }
}
```

And your `Error` view (I have it in `Views\Shared` directory) woul look as follows.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Blank.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Application Error";
}

@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

<h1>Application Error</h1>
@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
        Location: @Model.ControllerName/@Model.ActionName
    <br />
        Message: @Model.Exception.Message
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div>
        You've reached this page in error.
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Ok makes sense to me now. Thanks

Comment: Ok have added this and stepped thru it locally to see that it works. I deploy to my hosted server and it still throws a 500 server error and I never get to this code.

Comment: Sounds like error occurs before application runs. Could it be IIS config or Web.config errors? Also, could you check that `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` is included in your deployment package. I recently had a problem when I publish the application and this .dll would not be included for some reason (I used EF 6.0.1).