# migrations are not taking place after pushing my code on heroku...?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Well its been 12 hours and i'm still unable to deploy my project properly. I just dont know what is wrong happening. You guys can see throughing error that such models not exist . But i'm trying to make migrations my **heroku run python manage.py makemigrations** and it throughing me this traceback. My code is working perfectly fine in local but on the server side this is happening. Please help me out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/dotescrow/urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls',namespace = 'accounts')),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    from accounts import views
  File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from accounts.forms import UserCreateForm,CoustomLoginForm
  File "/app/accounts/forms.py", line 54, in <module>
    class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 268, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (gender, nationality, age) specified for User
PS C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow> heroku run python manage.py makemigrations 
Running python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ dotescrow... up, run.6085 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/dotescrow/urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls',namespace = 'accounts')),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/accounts/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from accounts import views
  File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from accounts.forms import UserCreateForm,CoustomLoginForm
  File "/app/accounts/forms.py", line 54, in <module>
    class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 268, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (age, nationality, gender) specified for User
```

**Usercreateform**

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ["first_name","last_name","username","email","password1","password2","age","gender","nationality"]
        model = User
        Gender = (
            ('one','Male'),
            ('two','Female'),
            )
        widgets ={
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'age' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'gender' : forms.Select(choices=Gender,attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'nationality' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'password1' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'password2' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email is invalid")
        return email

    def clean_age(self):
        age = self.cleaned_data["age"]
        print(age,'hm here')
        if age < 18:
            print(age,'hm here')
            raise forms.ValidationError("You age should be 18 plus")
        return age

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('First name')
        self.fields['first_name'].label = ''
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Last name')
        self.fields['last_name'].label = ''
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Username')
        self.fields['username'].label = ''
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Email')
        self.fields['email'].label = ''
        self.fields['age'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Age')
        self.fields['age'].label = ''
        self.fields['gender'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Gender')
        self.fields['gender'].label = ''
        self.fields['nationality'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Nationality')
        self.fields['nationality'].label = ''
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Password')
        self.fields['password1'].label = ''
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Confirm Password')
        self.fields['password2'].label = ''

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None
```

if more code is require then tell me in a comment session. i will update my question with that information.

Comment: I think the problem is in your `UserCreateForm`. Show it.

Comment: @TomWojcik i just added that

Answer (score 0):

You should not run `makemigrations` on heroku. Migrations is something that should be added to your repo and then your deployment plan uses those migration files to execute migrations on the DB.

Heroku has a `release` phase when `python manage.py migrate` should be executed. If migrations fail, new code that uses them won't be deployed.

If you don't want to add this phase because you don't feel like it - no problem. Just don't run `makemigrations`.

If, for some reason, you won't be able to create migrations locally, comment out this form, run `makemigrations`, run `migrate` and uncomment this code.

If heroku still complains, repeat these steps ^ on heroku as well.

But the idea is that on heroku you run only

- `python manage.py migrate` (`release` phase if possible)
- `gunicorn something something` (`web` dyno)